# PHP. Объединение 2-х массивов по id?

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка, объединение

столкнулся с проблемой при решении задачи. Есть 2 массива вида:

```
$arr1 = [
'8' => [
    'desc' => 0
],
'25' => [
    'desc' => 0
]];

$arr2 = [
    '0' => [
        'id'=>7,
        'say' => 'hello'
    ],
    '1'=> [
        'id'=>25,
        'say' => 'hi'
    ],
    '3' => [
        'id'=>25,
        'say' => 'Aloha'
    ]
];
```

Каким способом можно получить массив вида? Т.е слить 2 массива в один с привязкой к ключу $arr1

```
$output = [
'8' => [
    'desc' => 0,
    'say' => [
        1 => 'hello'
    ]
],
'25' => [
    'desc' => 0,
    'say' => [
        1 => 'hi',
        2 => 'Aloha'
    ]
]];
```

Comment: вы двойной цикл не можете написать?

Comment: Не получается, пробовал и foreachом, и просто forом. Бред выходит. Поэтому сюда и написал.

Comment: так надо приложить код, чтобы вам указали на ошибки.

Comment: Понял, прошу прощения, приложу код который получился в процессе решения.

Comment: Для ознакомления стоит прочесть [tour] и [ask].